# Block select/copying data in GridView with CTRL-A, CTRL-C

Tags: asp.net, winforms, visual-studio, gridview, devexpress

I want prevent use `CTRL-A, CTRL-C` (select and copy data from GridViews).

On this code i have some errors.

```
private void gridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

> Error    2    'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' does not contain a
>   definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error    3    The name 'Keys' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error    4    'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Control' and no extension method 'Control' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone help please?

Comment: Try using e.keydata or move this to your keypress event. Keypress is better if you wanna handle the keys.

Comment: private void gridView1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.C && e.Control)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
  
  
And I have only

"The name 'Keys' does not exist in the current contex" Move to Keypress event do norhing. I have same error.

Comment: These errors occur because you have System.Windows.Input namespace in the **using** section. This namespace came from a WPF library reference - PresentationCore.

Normally, you do not need to use PresentationCore library in a WinForms application, so you can remove it from the project references, as well as the namespace from the **using** section.

However, if you need this library for some reason and cannot remove it, just use the System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs and System.Windows.Forms.Keys.

Comment: I add "using System.Windows.Forms;" and error gone. But prevent select/copy not work. my full code http://freetexthost.com/ti6qq4xt3n